# iOSのコントロールセンターのようなUIを実現したいです。

Tags: swift, ios

初めまして。私は現在、カレンダーを利用したスケジュールアプリを開発しています。

そこで、下の画像（画面下半分、カレンダー部分の下）にあるように、viewの上端を上方向にスワイプすると、アニメーション付きで全画面表示に移行、下スワイプで元の表示に戻る、といった機能を実装するには、どうすれば良いのでしょうか？

[image]

ご教授いただければ幸いです。ご回答よろしくお願いします。

追記：

アドバイスありがとうございます。
以下の画像のように、私は、下半分のviewの上端に上方向のUISwipeGestureRecognizerを追加し、全画面表示の別のView Controllerへ画面遷移、そのView Controllerの上端に下方向のUISwipeGestureRecognizerを追加して画面を閉じることで似たような動きを実装しました。

しかし当然ですが、これは単なる画面遷移で、参考にしている機能とは根本的に異なる気がします。（参考の画像では、画面遷移するわけではなく、上方向にスワイプするとviewがそのまませり上がる感じです。）

開発経験もまだ浅く、どのように実装すれば良いか全く検討もつかない状態です。

ご回答よろしくお願いいたします。

[image]

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　こちらのご質問は、内容が具体的で趣旨が分かりやすいと思うのですが、このサイトでは「私のかわりに○○を実装してほしい」という類の質問には回答がつきにくいです。もし既にご自身で何かしらお試しになったコードがあれば、動かなくてもよいので、本文に追記して頂けませんでしょうか？　「このコードで○○のように動くと思ったのだが、実際は××のように動いてしまう」といった形式の方が回答が付きやすいからです。質問文下の「編集」から自由に追記ができます。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ご自身での実装(ちょっと違うんでしょうが、ひどいものとも思えません)内容を含めて、仕様についてきちんと記述しようとしてくださっており、仕様の細部まで回答者にお任せの丸投げ型質問とは一線を画しているとは思うのですが、やはり(今はうまく行っていないにしても)ご自身のコードを1行もあげておられない場合、回答がつきにくい傾向にあるかと思います。「以下の画像」を実装したコードを(できれば関係する部分をうまく抜き出して)ご提示いただいた方が、より回答がつきやすいだろうと思います。ただ、「開発経験もまだ浅く」とありますが、`UISwipeGestureRecognizer`を用いた画面遷移が普通に記述できるようですので、初心者の域はとうに卒業されているようです。iOSの「アニメーション」機能で、画面内のviewの大きさを変更することができる、と言うあたりにお気づきになれば、ご自身で実装できそうに思いますが、いかがでしょうか?

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。おっしゃる通り、アニメーション付きでviewの高さを変更するという機能を実装することで、無事解決できました

Answer (score 2):

アプローチは色々ありますけど、一番参考になれるものはアップルのデモと思います。

下記のwwdcの動画を参考いただければ分かると思います。
[アップル社のWWDC動画 WWDC 2017 - Session 230 - iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/230/)
まずは14分ごろのデモをチェックして確認してみてね。

コードの方は、こちらはGithubでのリークをご参考ください。
[Githubでのデモでした](https://github.com/kane-liu/AdvancedAnimations)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。まさに私が求めていた機能です。コードのリンクまで添えていただき本当にありがとうございます！